# BOOTSTRAP 4 => Error: Undefined operation: "null lt 9"

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I got an error in **bootstrap 4.0.0-beta** while trying to extend bootstrap grid breakpoints.
Notice: As long as I used the **bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6** there was no such error, and bootstrap grid breakpoints was successfully crerates.

[image]

Here is part of the code of file below:

```
node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_custom.scss
```

[image]

Here is same problem and SOLVE, but it doesn't helps for me: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20833

How do I solve this error?

Comment: Here is this troubleshooting function with my @debug below (screenshot):
https://s.mail.ru/GiTi/w7bRjBnbk

Comment: Made:`npm uninstall bootstrap --save`
and then: `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 --save` and project was build **SUCCESSFULLY** (Screenshot) https://s.mail.ru/KZBa/BCSQ7TZXh
BUT! I need **BETA!** =(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem. The fact is that in the file `/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_tables.scss` the function call comes with a hard binding to the argument, which we re-recorded when the file was customized `/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss` via `/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_custom.scss`. All that is required to FIX it is to do a relative binding in the argument of the function, or simply change argument "In my case from **md** to **m**"

[image]

I have also will say it to developers here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20833